# Laravel: get models if count of relation has some condition

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have User and UserComplains Models.
I like to retrieve users that have UserComplains more than 2 times in the last 24 hours.

```
users:
id

user_complains:
complained_id ->ref-> users.id
created_at
```

this is what I tried and it is working:

```
$users = User::select('users.*')->join('user_complains' , 'users.id' , '=' , 'user_complains.complained_id')
        ->whereRaw("(
        select count(*) from `user_complains`
        where `user_complains`.`complained_id` = `users`.`id`
        and `user_complains`.`created_at` > ?) >= ?" , [now()->subHours(24), 2])
        ->groupBy("users.id")
        ->get();
```

the above code is fine and is working, but I wonder is there a better way to do that?!

Comment: Does you have a relationship set up in your `User` model for `user_complains`? If so, please can you add it to your question.

Comment: If the relationship exists then you can [Query relationship existence](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) by using `whereHas`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For something like this you can use [whereHas()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence). :

```
$users = User::whereHas('*relationship*', function ($query) {
    $query->where('created_at', '>=', now()->subDay(1));
}, '>', 2)->get();
```

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence), you can pass additional checks as the 3rd and 4th param so in this case you want to say where the user has more that 2 `user_complains`.

**NB** You will need to replace `*relationship*` with the actual name of the relationship.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
User::whereHas('complaints', function($query) {
   $query->where('created_at', '>=', '2020-04-26');
}, '>', 2)->get();
```

In order for this to work though you need to have set up a relationship between your `User` and `UserComplaint` models.

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function complaints()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(UserComplaint:class);
    }
}
```